# Повторение кода в разных классах(рефакторинг)

Tags: php, рефакторинг, javascript

Привет.
Подскажите процедуру по выделению повторяемого кода который имеется в разных классах.Какие существуют проблемы(вот здесь хотелось более детально раздуть проблему,например изменения переменных-свойств)?
Если нужно выделить повторяемый код внутри одного класса так вроде все понятно:выделяем повторяемый участок кода в отдельный метод и используем его.

Примеры интересуют на js либо на  php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то интересует следующее:

1. [Шаблон "Декоратор"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))
2. [Шаблон делегирования](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
3. Для JS - [одалживание метода](https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply#%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)